# Need help with long equation

Tags: equations

I need help with this equation. I'm trying to put it in one column and multiple lines and make it look nice.

The format of the latex document is two-column. So (obviously) it has to fit in 1 column.

Also, it's a long equation, so it has to be on multiple lines.

Here is the image and code...[image]

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(0)  & = & (1 - A) \\ \nonumber
P(1) & = & (1 - A)(e^A - 1)  \nonumber
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{multline}
\label{md1ssprob}
P(i + 1)  =  \frac{1}{P(0,A)} \left\{ P(i) - [P(0) + P(1)] \cdot P(i,A) \right. \\
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad    \left. - \sum_{\nu=2}^{i} P(\nu) \cdot P(i - \nu + 1, A) \right\}. 
\end{multline}
```

I tried eqnarry, mutline, etc. I can't seem to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What would like to have instead?

Comment: The same equation - all in one latex line code - is that possible?

Comment: See the space below $P(1) = ...$ - that does not look good...

Comment: It is possible in many journals to have a full-width equation despite a two-column layout.  Your journal may have instructions for that.  In the middle of the page it often disrupts the reading flow though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slighly different layout with àlignat`and`fleqn:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[47]
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{alignat}{2}%
 & P(0) = (1 - A) \notag \\
 & P(1) = (1 - A)\mathrlap{(e^A - 1)}\notag \\
 & P(i + 1) =
\frac{1}{P(0,A)}\Bigl\{P(i) &&- [P(0) + P(1)] \cdot \mathrlap{P(i,A) }\notag\\
 & &\mathllap{-\sum_{\nu=2}^{i} P(\nu) }& \cdot P(i - \nu + 1, A) \Bigr\}.
\label{md1ssprob}
\end{alignat}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks even better now...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

The follow looks decent. Just [avoid using `eqnarray`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764).

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{align}
      P(0) &= (1 - A) \nonumber \\
      P(1) &= (1 - A)(e^A - 1) \nonumber \\
  P(i + 1) &= \frac{1}{P(0,A)} \biggl\{
                P(i) - \bigl[ P(0) + P(1) \bigr] \cdot P(i, A) \nonumber \\
           &\quad {} - \sum_{\nu = 2}^i P(\nu) \cdot P(i - \nu + 1, A) \biggr\}. 
\end{align}
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Looks great!